# Consultas sql con sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Os escribo para ver qué falla en esta consulta:
Nombre del profesor que imparte todas las asignaturas de primero

```
select 
    nombre
from profesor inner join imparte on (profesor.p# = imparte.p#)
group by nombre
having (curso like "primero")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La cláusula **having** funciona cuando usas un agrupamiento. Según el query que publicaste deberías usar un **where**

```
SELECT 
    nombre
FROM profesor INNER JOIN imparte ON (profesor.p# = imparte.p#)
WHERE curso LIKE 'primero'
```

- Ten en cuenta los literales, van con comilla sencilla, no con doble.
- En este caso, el like funciona como un igual ( = ), cambia tu consulta para que sea `curso = 'primero'`
- El campo `curso` debes especificar de cual tabla proviene, es para evitar ambiguiedades.

---

Revisa [la cláusula having](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) para que tengas idea del uso de agrupamientos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Solamente si quisieras tener el nombre de los maestros sin registros repetidos, por ejemplo si un profesor imparte dos materias aparecerá dos veces, solo deberías agregar DISTINCT